# SQL Server How to get number of unique values in a column and average score per values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, average

I have a table like this

```
city        metric_name      metric_value   id
Berlin      likes            1              1a
Berlin      dislikes         2              1a 
Berlin      comments         3              1a

Berlin      likes            4              1b
Berlin      dislikes         5              1b
Berlin      comments         3              1b

Hamburg     likes            1              1c
Hamburg     dislikes         2              1c
Hamburg     comments         3              1c

Hamburg     likes            2              1d
Hamburg     dislikes         4              1d
Hamburg     comments         5              1d
```

and so on

```
My ideal result is this

city        city_count_unique   average_metric_score
Berlin      2                   3 (sum metric_value / sum metric_names)
Hamburg     2                   2,8
```

What I ve done

I got distinct count for every city and avg metric value

```
SELECT AVG(T.metric_value), T.city,
COUNT(*) AS 'city_count_unique'
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT metric_value, city
    FROM dbo.Table) as T
GROUP BY T.city
```

But it is false

Appreciate any help

## updated

There is also an additional column id in varchar format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer here depends on this assumption:

> You always have exactly 3 metrics per 'group' (i.e. likes, dislikes
>   and comments)

If that assumption is correct, the following will output what you are looking for:

```
SELECT  city,
        COUNT(metric_name) / 3 AS city_count_unique,
        CAST(SUM(metric_value) AS FLOAT) / COUNT(metric_value) AS average_metric_score
  FROM  #Table
  GROUP BY city
```

Output:

```
city    city_count_unique   average_metric_score
Berlin  2                   3
Hamburg 2                   2.83333333333333
```

**How does this work?**

By grouping on the city, we combine results for each city individually.

The count of `metric_name` gives the total metrics for that city (which is 6 in the case of your example).  I divide this by 3 to give the unique count (based on the assumption I stated).

The `average_metric_score` calculation if the total of the `metric_value` for each city divided by the number of metrics (so 18 / 6 for `Berlin`).  The reason for the `CAST` to `FLOAT` is to allow for a floating point answer.  You could also use `CONVERT` if you prefer this to `CAST`.

**Edit following OP update to question**

OP edited the question to indicate that there is an ID column that allows the detection of metric grouping.  This is an update to use that rather than assuming there are always 3 metrics per group.

```
SELECT  city,
        COUNT(id) AS city_count_unique,
        CAST(SUM(metric_value_total) AS FLOAT) / SUM(metric_value_count) AS average_metric_score
  FROM  (
        SELECT  city,
                id,
                SUM(metric_value) metric_value_total,
                COUNT(metric_value) AS metric_value_count
          FROM  #Table
          GROUP BY city, id
        ) a
  GROUP BY city
```

Comment: Hello, unfortunately, the number of metrics can vary (

Comment: @AnnaDmitrieva In that case, how would you ever know how many there were? Is there a way of calculating it?

Comment: I updated the question, there is an id column, like I have to count ids for every city, but never worked with SQL no idea how to combine it all in one view

Comment: @AnnaDmitrieva I've updated the answer based on the new information you provided

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want:

```
SELECT city,
       COUNT(DISTINCT id) as city_count_unique,
       AVG(metric_value * 1.0) as average_metric_score
FROM t
GROUP BY city;
```